# float is getting mangled when passing between methods (typecasting problem?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, floating-point, casting

I'm having trouble passing a float value from one object to another. It appears to be fine in the first method, but in the second its value is huge. I assume this is some kind of a problem with my typecasting, because that's the thing I understand the poorest. Help is greatly appreciated!

In my game controller, I do this:

```
float accuracy = (float)hitCount/(float)(hitCount+missCount);
NSLog(@"GameController - hits: %i misses: %i enemies: %i accuracy: %f", hitCount, missCount, escapedCount, accuracy);
[delegate postGameWithScore:roundScore andAccuracy:accuracy];
```

Which invokes this method in the game controller's delegate:

```
-(void)postGameWithScore:(NSInteger)score andAccuracy:(float)accuracy {
    cumulativeScore += score;
    NSLog(@"GameMaster - score: %i accuracy %f",cumulativeScore, accuracy);
    /* non relevant code clipped */
}
```

Output:

```
GameController - hits: 14 misses: 54 enemies: 35 accuracy: 0.205882
GameMaster - score: 3800 accuracy 36893488147419103232.000000
```

I can't figure out why `accuracy` is not correct in the second NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!! solved it.

Adding this to my delegate's header fixed it:

```
-(void)postGameWithScore:(NSInteger)score andAccuracy:(float)accuracy;
```

Don't know why this fixed it, but that'll teach me to treat compiler warnings as warnings instead of errors.

Comment: If you don't specify the header, the values will be all passed as integers (but for some reason it becomes 0x60000000). Converting that into to `float` representations gives the garbage (3.68935e+19).

Comment: There is a build setting in Xcode named “Treat Warnings as Errors”. Turn that on. While you're at it, here's a bunch of other warnings you should turn on: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings